# integers $n$ such that $(n-1)!+1$ is a power of $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Please, find all positive integers n for which (n-1)! +1 is a power of n.

Comment: Please tell us what you've tried and where you are stuck. Also consult Wilson's theorem to drastically reduce the problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem

Comment: I just listed the numbers and computed them, i wanna find their pattern

Comment: How many numbers did you list? What partial results can you give us?

Comment: You have to tell us detail.

Comment: Without the details of what you've tried, this Question is likely to be placed on-hold until those are added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We're solving the equation $(n-1)!+1=n^m$, $n,m\in\mathbb Z^+$.

$n=p$ is prime, because $n=1$ gives no solutions and if $n>1$ is composite, we get a contradiction mod a prime divisor of $n$.

If $p=2$, then $(p,m)=(2,1)$. If $p=3$, then $(p,m)=(3,1)$. If $p=5$, then $(p,m)=(5,2)$. Let $p>5$. Clearly $m\ge 3$.

$p^m-1=(p-1)!$ is equivalent to $$p^{m-1}+p^{m-2}+\cdots+1=(p-2)!$$

$2<\frac{p-1}{2}< p-2$, so $p-1\mid (p-2)!$.

$$1^{m-1}+1^{m-2}+\cdots+1\equiv 0\pmod{p-1},$$ i.e. $p-1\mid m$, so $p-1\le m$, so

$$p^m\ge p^{p-1}=\underbrace{p\cdot p\cdots p}_{p-1}$$

$$>\underbrace{(p-1)\cdot (p-2)\cdots 2\cdot 1}_{p-1}+1=(p-1)!+1$$

Comment: If n is composite, why do we take a contradiction? Please, give me why it is a contradiction

Comment: @Mobius6 Let $n>1$ be composite and let $p$ be a prime divisor of $n$ (therefore $p\mid n$ and so $p\mid n^m$). Then $1<p<n-1$, so $p\mid (n-1)!$. Therefore $p\mid n^m-(n-1)!=1$, so $p\mid 1$, so $p=\pm 1$, contradiction.